# How to remove words from values start with an specific word exp @specificword

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have images which have an attribute aria-label with values. As example

```
aria-label="And just like that we wake up and it appears we live by the ocean... ;)
@ReverieRetreat #Reverieretreat #Retreatcenter #Reverie #SierraFoothills
#Eldoradocounty #infinitypool
#ElDoradoCountyCa #VisitEldoradocounty @visiteldorado #VisitEldorado #VisitGoldcountry #Goldcountry #California
#VisitCalifornia @VisitCalifornia #applehill @applehillofficial 
#tasteintravel #adventureseeker #lovetravel #travelnow @natgeotravel #natgeotravel
#local #sacramento #natgeotravel"
```

Here I want to remove words starting with @ and # also remove words from the first word here which is @ReverieRetreat

Please someone help me how can I do that.

Comment: *also remove words from the first word here which is @ReverieRetreat* - this part isn't clear as you'll already be removing @ReverieRetreat as it starts with @ and "words from the first word???"

Comment: try to use RegEx

Comment: Regex: `\B\@\w+` for words starting with @ and `\B\#\w+` for words starting with #

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. @freedomn-m All of the values have the same words which are '@ReverieRetreat' and I want to remove words starting from this to the end. Is that possible?  Also, I am not an expert. Can someone please help me to give an example of jquery code for this?

Comment: Please someone help me, please.